# Using realloc() crahes program

Tags: c, realloc

I have some problems using `realloc()`, so I made a sample program to illustrate the problem using as less code as possible.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned long long *a;
    srand(time(NULL));
    a = malloc(sizeof(unsigned long long));
    for (i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = rand() % 32;
        printf("%llu\n", a[i]);
        a = realloc(a, (i + 1) * sizeof(unsigned long long));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

> *** glibc detected**  demo: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000000dc3010 **

Why does this crash?

**Edit:**
I tried chaning `(i + 1)` to `(i + 2)` and then the program worked, but I do not understand why. I only request to extend the memory space by **one** `unsigned long long`.

Comment: are you not getting any compilation error ?

Comment: No. This is a runtime message.

Comment: It has to access an array outside the secured.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first time your loop runs, `i` is equal to `0`. You realloc `a` to hold `i + 1` elements, which is... `1` !
The second time your loop runs, you try to write to `a[i]` with `i == 1`, which is the *second* element of your array. But since your array can only hold `1` element, that can cause a crash.

Comment: very good Nbr! its due to buffer overflow but because of `relloc()` function correct?

Comment: Yes, but only because the reallocation itself is too small. As another answerer mentioned, it should be `i + 2` to hold one more element than the current amount.

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating location `i` but accessing location `i+1`

**And do not forget to free the allocated memory before exiting**

```
free(a);
```

So do this modification to make this code work

`a = realloc(a, (i + 2) * sizeof(unsigned long long)); // ERROR HERE`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

    int main(void)
    {
        unsigned int i;
        unsigned long long *a;
        srand(time(NULL));
        a = malloc(sizeof(unsigned long long));
        for (i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
        {
            a[i] = rand() % 32;
            printf("%llu\n", a[i]);
            a = realloc(a, (i + 1) * sizeof(unsigned long long)); // ERROR HERE
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Oh, yes forgot to mention: I tried that and then it worked, but I do not understand why. Will update post in a sec.